# Как соединить php и jabber bot?

Tags: php, wordpress, бот, xmpp

Возможно ли используя php управлять jabber ботом?

Я собираюсь использовать WordPress как CMS.

Comment: Hello. Our working language is a Russian. If you want to ask a question in English, you should visit https://stackoverflow.com/